# Using R, how to assign a category into a new column based on a date in another column and carry that value forward until the next date?

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with approximately 3 million rows. Each row is assigned a unique ID and has up to 4 dates. I wish to create a set of new columns for month and year (i.e. Jan-21, Feb-21, Mar-21, etc) and assign a value of "0" for each month/year prior to the first date, and then a value of "1" for the month/year containing the date for each ID, and maintain the value of "1" in each subsequent month/year column until the next column that matches the 2nd date.

I understand that it's easier to help me with examples, so I have put together this dput output with an example of what my current data looks like:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), date1 = structure(c(1623801600, 
1615420800, 1654560000, 1620259200, 1615248000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), date2 = structure(c(1629158400, 1621987200, 
1658448000, 1623974400, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    date3 = structure(c(NA, 1630454400, 1662076800, 1647907200, 
    NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), date4 = structure(c(NA, 
    1639008000, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

And this is what I would like it to look like:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), `Mar-21` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 
1), `Apr-21` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1), `May-21` = c(0, 2, 0, 1, 1), 
    `Jun-21` = c(1, 2, 0, 2, 1), `Jul-21` = c(1, 2, 0, 2, 1), 
    `Aug-21` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 1), `Sep-21` = c(2, 3, 0, 2, 1), 
    `Oct-21` = c(2, 3, 0, 2, 1), `Nov-21` = c(2, 3, 0, 2, 1), 
    `Dec-21` = c(2, 4, 0, 2, 1), `Jan-22` = c(2, 4, 0, 2, 1), 
    `Feb-22` = c(2, 4, 0, 2, 1), `Mar-22` = c(2, 4, 0, 3, 1), 
    `Apr-22` = c(2, 4, 0, 3, 1), `May-22` = c(2, 4, 0, 3, 1), 
    `Jun-22` = c(2, 4, 1, 3, 1), `Jul-22` = c(2, 4, 2, 3, 1), 
    `Aug-22` = c(2, 4, 2, 3, 1), `Sep-22` = c(2, 4, 3, 3, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Just a note that I have this dataset in both wide and long format, in case using it in a long format makes more sense.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a fun exercise! I'm sure there are a billion ways to do this more efficiently, but I think this works and was a fun puzzle for me. I first put the dates into long format to get a min and max. Then I made a sequence of those dates by month. I then used expand grid to make all combinations of the months with each ID to join it to the original data frame. Then I just summed how many dates1:4 were greater then the months in the list. I had to use floor_date to change dates1:4 to the first of the month. Hopefully this helps!

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
dat2<-dat%>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_drop_na = T)

dat_min_max<-data.frame("Min" = min(dat2$value), "Max" = max(dat2$value))
month_seq<-seq(dat_min_max$Min, dat_min_max$Max+months(1), by = "month")

dat3<-dat%>%
  mutate(date1 = floor_date(date1, "month"),
         date2 = floor_date(date2, "month"),
         date3 = floor_date(date3, "month"),
         date4 = floor_date(date4, "month")
         )%>%
  left_join(expand.grid(dat$id, month_seq), by = c("id" = "Var1"))%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(c = sum(date1 <= Var2, date2 <= Var2, date3 <= Var2, date4 <= Var2, na.rm = T))%>%
  mutate(Var2 = format(Var2, "%b-%y"))%>%
  select(-date1, -date2, -date3, -date4)%>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Var2, values_from = c)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! Your answer worked on a small dataset, but unfortunately when I tried to scale it up to my full dataset, it exceeded the memory limit on our server. In the end I just spend 15 minutes typing it out using mutate/case_when for each month, and just carried the last value forward if each cell didn't fit within the range of each month. Much less elegant and efficient than your solution but it worked!